# Why the REPL is not showing the full trace of the function call?

Tags: common-lisp, trace, slime

I am trying to learn Common Lisp with the book *Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to Symbolic Computation*. In addition, I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime.

In the advanced section of chapter 7, the author suggests the use of the trace function. This is definetly a really valuable tool. I was glad to see it working.

However, apparently, my tool does not work **fully** as the one presented by the author.

After doing the following definition:

```
(defun find-first-odd (x)
   (find-if #’oddp x))
```

And running on the REPL:

```
> (dtrace find-first-odd oddp)
```

He gets:

```
> (find-first-odd ’(2 4 6 7 8))
----Enter FIND-FIRST-ODD
| X = (2 4 6 7 8)
| ----Enter ODDP
| | NUMBER = 2
| \--ODDP returned NIL
| ----Enter ODDP
| | NUMBER = 4
| \--ODDP returned NIL
| ----Enter ODDP
| | NUMBER = 6
| \--ODDP returned NIL
| ----Enter ODDP
| | NUMBER = 7
| \--ODDP returned T
\--FIND-FIRST-ODD returned 7
7
```

On my environment, using the same definition:

```
(defun find-first-odd (x)
   (find-if #’oddp x))
```

And doing the trace (with a sanity check):

```
CL-USER> (trace)
NIL
CL-USER> (trace find-first-odd oddp)
(FIND-FIRST-ODD ODDP)
```

I get:

```
CL-USER> (find-first-odd '(2 4 6 7 8))
  0: (FIND-FIRST-ODD (2 4 6 7 8))
  0: FIND-FIRST-ODD returned 7
```

This seems awkward since the `(trace)` evaluation **indicates the inclusion of the odd predicate.** However, after the function call it does not appear as a traced operation.

In another example in which both of my functions were definied by me and no primitive such as `oddp` predicate were involved, it worked perfectly:

```
(defun half (n) (* n 0.5))

(defun average (x y)
  (+ (half x) (half y)))

CL-USER> (trace half average)
(HALF AVERAGE)

CL-USER> (average 3 7)
  0: (AVERAGE 3 7)
    1: (HALF 3)
    1: HALF returned 1.5
    1: (HALF 7)
    1: HALF returned 3.5
  0: AVERAGE returned 5.0
5.0
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `trace` on multiple functions, and you need to call `trace` on each function for which you want to see trace information. So, you can do:

```
CL-USER> (trace find-first-odd oddp)
(FIND-FIRST-ODD ODDP)
CL-USER> (find-first-odd '(2 4 6 7 8))
  0: (FIND-FIRST-ODD (2 4 6 7 8))
  0: FIND-FIRST-ODD returned 7
7
```

But, built-in functions may not produce any trace information, and it looks like `oddp` is not traceable in SBCL. This is probably because `oddp` is inlined in SBCL. You can try using the `notinline` declaration:

```lisp
(defun find-first-odd (x)
  (declare (notinline oddp))
  (find-if #'oddp x))
```

```
CL-USER> (trace find-first-odd oddp)
(FIND-FIRST-ODD ODDP)
CL-USER> (find-first-odd '(2 4 6 7 8))
  0: (FIND-FIRST-ODD (2 4 6 7 8))
    1: (ODDP 2)
    1: ODDP returned NIL
    1: (ODDP 4)
    1: ODDP returned NIL
    1: (ODDP 6)
    1: ODDP returned NIL
    1: (ODDP 7)
    1: ODDP returned T
  0: FIND-FIRST-ODD returned 7
7
```

Failing that, you may wrap a built in function in another function definition which can be traced:

```lisp
(defun my-oddp (&rest args)
    (apply #'oddp args))

(defun find-first-odd-trace (x)
  (find-if #'my-oddp x))
```

```
CL-USER> (untrace)
T
CL-USER> (trace find-first-odd-trace my-oddp)
(FIND-FIRST-ODD-TRACE MY-ODDP)
CL-USER> (find-first-odd-trace '(2 4 6 7 8))
  0: (FIND-FIRST-ODD-TRACE (2 4 6 7 8))
    1: (MY-ODDP 2)
    1: MY-ODDP returned NIL
    1: (MY-ODDP 4)
    1: MY-ODDP returned NIL
    1: (MY-ODDP 6)
    1: MY-ODDP returned NIL
    1: (MY-ODDP 7)
    1: MY-ODDP returned T
  0: FIND-FIRST-ODD-TRACE returned 7
7
```

You might want to see the call to `find-if`, too. Here you can see that, while `find-if` is a built-in function, in SBCL it is traceable:

```
CL-USER> (trace find-if)
(FIND-IF)
CL-USER> (find-first-odd-trace '(2 4 6 7 8))
  0: (FIND-FIRST-ODD-TRACE (2 4 6 7 8))
    1: (FIND-IF #<FUNCTION SB-IMPL::ENCAPSULATION {100307F6AB}> (2 4 6 7 8))
      2: (MY-ODDP 2)
      2: MY-ODDP returned NIL
      2: (MY-ODDP 4)
      2: MY-ODDP returned NIL
      2: (MY-ODDP 6)
      2: MY-ODDP returned NIL
      2: (MY-ODDP 7)
      2: MY-ODDP returned T
    1: FIND-IF returned 7
  0: FIND-FIRST-ODD-TRACE returned 7
7
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you find that info? Did you look at the SBCL's manual? Which topic?

Comment: @PedroDelfino -- from the REPL you can see documentation for `trace` by calling `(documentation 'trace 'function)`. There is also information in the SBCL manual. Section 4.5 reminded me that you can declare a built-in function `notinline`, so I added a bit about that to my answer. Section 5.9 is about function tracing.